# Missing attachment on xhr download with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, download, xmlhttprequest, htmlunit

I'm trying to automate some file download (using HtmlUnit) from a website that is based on a liferay+struts+angular.
HtmlUnit has done a fine job in navigating pages and interpreting JS so far, but when I try to download the file, it returns me the same page and not the attachment.

The download button is made as such:

```html
<button class="btn" name="filedownload" data-ng-disabled="false"
        type="button" data-ng-lick="vm.downloadFile(...things...)">
</button>
```

I've already tried with the two main techniques that I've found online: using a `CollectingAttachmentHandler` and `.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream()`, both of them give me the starting page and not the attachment.

By tracing it with the network tracer of Chrome I see that once I clicked it makes a call to 2 different endpoints, the first to trace that such file will be doenloaded and the second to download the file, the second one has a response with the correct `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=` header, but apparently HtmlUnit is not picking it up.

Here is some snippet of the code that I've tried.

```java
CollectingAttachmentHandler attachmentHandler = new 
CollectingAttachmentHandler();
client.setAttachmentHandler(attachmentHandler);
attachmentHandler.handleAttachment(myButton.click());

// I get only one attachment, the page
List<Attachment> attachments = attachmentHandler.getCollectedAttachments();
```

```java
try (InputStream in = myButton.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
     OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(new File(""...my_file...).toPath())) {
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
}
// In my file I find the page
```

**Edit:**
I've opened a ticket in HtmlUnit's github, the author was generous enogh to reply and give me some suggestions, such as checking if new windows were opened with `client.getWebWindows()`. That is not my case ufortunately, but I also post it here in case someone finds it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

At least you can use the WebConnectionWrapper to intercept/ get notified of all request-response cycles.
See http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse for a short sample.